# SNOWFLAKE: Can't assign MASKING POLICY to TAG

Tags: tags, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-masking

I'm trying to assign a masking policy to tag in snowflake but I'm having trouble with required privilege or object missing depending on the role I'm using.

How I proceed :

```
use database DATABASE;
use schema SCHEMA;

--CREATE TAG
create or replace tag sensitive_values; 

--CREATE MASKING POLICY 
create or replace masking policy values_mask as (val int) returns int ->
 case
   when current_role() in ('SYSADMIN') then val
   else null 
 end;

--ASSOCIATE MASKING POILCY AND TAG 
alter tag DATABASE.SCHEMA.sensitive_values set masking policy values_mask;
```

When I'm using the role **SECURITYADMIN** I have this error: `SQL compilation error: Database 'DATABASE' does not exist or not authorized.`

When I'm using the role **SYSADMIN** I have this error : `SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on tag 'SENSITIVE_VALUES'`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try with role ACCOUNT_ADMIN or MASKING_ADMIN.

Comment: Also, calling your database and schema DATABASE and SCHEMA (if that’s what you’re doing) is a really bad idea

Comment: Verify your role has the privileges required. Best practice would be to make a custom role -> grant privileges -> grant custom role (such as sysadmin, or custom) which will inherit the privileges. example:
create role tag_admin;
grant create tag on schema <schema_name> to role tag_admin;
grant apply tag on account to role tag_admin; 
grant apply masking policy on account to role tag_admin;
grant role tag_admin to role <some_role>;

Comment: @NickW I juste use this name for the question, I'm not using it in my actual snowflake.

Comment: @GregPavlik This accounts don't exist on my snowflake.

Comment: @TomMeacham I will try creating a custom role as you describe.

Comment: @user15915737 The accountadmin and masking_admin roles are built-in. Someone should have accountadmin. Check around for who has it.

Comment: @GregPavlik see my answer, I have use it for my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @TomMeacham, I have create a specific role to manage my tag:

```
--CREATE ROLE
use role securityadmin;

create role tag_admin comment = "Admin role manage tag";


GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE DATABASE_NAME TO ROLE tag_admin;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME TO ROLE tag_admin;

grant create masking policy on schema DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME to role tag_admin;
grant create tag on schema DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME to role tag_admin;

use role accountadmin;
grant apply tag on account to tag_admin;
grant apply masking policy on account to role tag_admin;

GRANT ROLE tag_admin TO USER USER_NAME; 

--ASSIGN TAG TO MASKING POLICY 
use role tag_admin;

use database DATABASE_NAME;
use schema SCHEMA_NAME;

alter tag DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.sensitive_values set masking policy values_mask;
```

Now the tag is assign to the masking policy.